# Dropwizard registering two classes/clients

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

I have two instances of clients with different configs  that I am creating (timeout, threadpool, etc...), and would like to leverage Dropwizard's metric on both of the clients.

```
        final JerseyClientBuilder jerseyClientBuilder = new JerseyClientBuilder(environment)
            .using(configuration.getJerseyClientConfiguration());

        final Client config1Client = jerseyClientBuilder.build("config1Client");
        environment.jersey().register(config1Client);

        final Client config2Client = jerseyClientBuilder.build("config2Client");
        environment.jersey().register(config2Client);
```

However, I am getting

```
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors: The following warnings have been detected: 
HINT: Cannot create new registration for component type class org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient: 
Existing previous registration found for the type.
```

And only one client's metric shows up.

How do I track both clients' metrics or is it not common to have 2 clients in a single dropwizard app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, turned out I was an idiot (for trying to save some resource on the ClientBuilder).

2 Things that I did wrong with my original code:
1. You don't need to register Jersey clients, just the resource is enough... somehow I missed the resource part in my code and just straight up trying to register the client
2. You need to explicitly build each JerseyClientBuilder and then build your individually configured clients, then dropwizard will fetch by each JerseyClientBuilder's metrics

In the end, I just had to change my code to the following:

```
    final Client config1Client = new JerseyClientBuilder(environment)
        .using(configuration.getJerseyClientConfiguration()).build("config1Client");


    final Client config2Client = new JerseyClientBuilder(environment)
        .using(configuration.getJerseyClientConfiguration()).build("config2Client");
```

Doh.

Answer (score -1):

`environment.jersey().register()` has a javadoc listing of `Adds the given object as a Jersey singleton component` meaning that the objects registered become part of the jersey dependency injection framework. Specifically this method is used to add resource classes to the jersey context, but any object with an annotation or type that Jersey looks for can be added this way. Additionally, since they are singletons you can only have one of them per any concrete type (which is why you are getting a "previous registration" error from Jersey).

I imagine that you want to have two Jersey clients to connect to two different external services via REST/HTTP. Since your service needs to talk to these others to do *its* work, you'll want to have the clients accessible wherever the "work" or business logic is being performed.

For example, [this guide](http://javaeeeee.blogspot.com/2015/12/getting-started-with-dropwizard.html) creates a *resource* class that requires a client to an external http service to do currency conversions. I'm not saying this is a great example (just a top google result for `dropwizard external client example`). In fact, I think this not a good to structure your application. I'd create several internal objects that hide from the resource class how the currency information is fetched, like a business object (BO) or data access object (DAO), etc.

For your case, you might want something like this (think of these as constructor calls). JC = jersey client, R = resource object, BO = business logic object

```
JC1()
JC2()
B1(JC1)
B2(JC2)
R1(B1)
R2(B2)
R3(B1, B2)
environment.jersey().register(R1)
environment.jersey().register(R2)
environment.jersey().register(R3)
```

The [official Dropwizard docs](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.1.2/docs/manual/client.html) are somewhat helpful. They at least explain how to create a jersey client; they don't explain how to structure your application.

If you're using the Jersey client builder *from dropwizard*, each of the clients that you create should be automatically registered to record metrics. Make sure you're using the client builder from the `dropwizard-client` artifact and package `io.dropwizard.client`. (Looks like you are because you have the `using(config)` method.)